Problemas com tkinter e ctkinter ao fechar janela
Comecei a programar em python faz pouco tempo, e estou usando a biblioteca ctkinter e tkinter para fazer uma aplicação, e estou tendo problemas envolvendo um erro:
     while executing "1849134836800update"
     ("after" script) invalid command name "1849134837696check_dpi_scaling"
     while executing "1849134837696check_dpi_scaling"
     ("after" script)

Acho que o código está tentando executar com a janela fechada, mas não sei como resolver, abaixo está o código, se alguém estiver disposto a me ajudar, agradeço.
Obs: A janela fecha normalmente e abre o menu, mas o erro continua ocorrendo, estou apenas confuso, e não quero manter este erro até o final do meu projeto.
import customtkinter as ctk
from tkinter import *
import sqlite3
import menu as my_menu
from tkinter import messagebox

class backend():
        
    def conecta_db(self):
        self.conn = sqlite3.connect("banco.db")
        self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()
        print("banco de dados conectado com sucesso")        
    
    def desconecta_db(self):
        self.conn.close()
        print("banco de dados desconectado")

    def cria_tabela(self):
        self.conecta_db()
        self.cursor.execute("""
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS usuarios(
        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
        nome TEXT NOT NULL,
        senha TEXT NOT NULL,
        confirma_senha TEXT NOT NULL
        );
        """)
        self.conn.commit()
        print("tabela criada com sucesso")
        self.desconecta_db()

    def cadastrar_usuario(self):
        self.nome_cadastro = self.cadastro_nome_entry.get()
        self.senha_cadastro = self.cadastro_senha_entry.get()
        self.csenha_cadastro = self.cadastro_csenha_entry.get()

        self.conecta_db()
        self.cursor.execute("""
            INSERT INTO usuarios(nome, senha, confirma_senha)
            VALUES (?, ?, ?)""", (self.nome_cadastro, self.senha_cadastro, self.csenha_cadastro))    

        try:
            if (self.nome_cadastro == "" or self.senha_cadastro=="" or self.csenha_cadastro==""):
                messagebox.showerror(title="Erro no cadastro", message="Preencha todos os campos!")
            elif (self.senha_cadastro != self.csenha_cadastro):
                messagebox.showerror(title="Erro no cadastro", message="A senha precisa ser igual em ambas entradas")
            else:
                self.conn.commit()
                messagebox.showinfo(title="Cadastro concluido", message=f"{self.nome_cadastro},\nSeu cadastro foi concluido!")
                print("Dados cadastrados com sucesso!")
                self.desconecta_db()
                
        except:
            messagebox.showerror(title="Erro no cadastro", message="Erro no processamento, por favor tente novamente!")
            self.desconecta_db()

    def verificar_login(self):
        self.nome_login = self.nome_entry.get()
        self.senha_login = self.senha_entry.get()
        
        self.conecta_db()

        self.cursor.execute("""SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE (nome = ? AND senha = ?)""", (self.nome_login, self.senha_login))
        self.verifica_dados = self.cursor.fetchone() #procurando na tabela usuarios

        try:
            if (self.nome_login in self.verifica_dados and self.senha_login in self.verifica_dados):
                messagebox.showinfo(title="Login Aprovado", message=f"{self.nome_login}, bem-vindo(a)!")
                self.desconecta_db()
                self.fecha_login()
                self.abre_menu()
                
               
                
        except:
            messagebox.showerror(title="Erro no Login", message="Seus dados não foram encontrados no sistema, Verifique seus dados, ou cadastre-se.")
            self.desconecta_db()
            pass


class App(ctk.CTk, backend):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.config_da_janela_login()
        self.tela_login()
        self.cria_tabela()
        self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.fecha_login)
        self.janela_login = self
        self.janela_aberta = True
        
        

    def config_da_janela_login(self):
        self.geometry("1280x720")
        self.title("Login")
        self.resizable(False, False)

    def tela_login(self):

        #frame formulario
        self.frame_login = ctk.CTkFrame(self, width=426 , height=580)
        self.frame_login.place(x=426, y=70)
        self.login_titulo = ctk.CTkLabel(master=self.frame_login, text="LOGIN",  font=("arial",30))
        self.login_titulo.place(x=170, y=30)

        #entrys
        self.nome_entry= ctk.CTkEntry(self.frame_login, width=300, height=40, placeholder_text="Seu nome", border_color="#871fff", corner_radius=15)
        self.nome_entry.place(x=60, y=120)

        self.senha_entry= ctk.CTkEntry(self.frame_login, width=300, height=40, placeholder_text="Sua senha", show="*", corner_radius=15, border_color="#871fff")
        self.senha_entry.place(x=60, y=240)

        self.botao_login= ctk.CTkButton(self.frame_login, text="Login", width=200, height=40, corner_radius=20, fg_color="#871fff", hover_color="#9a42ff", command=self.verificar_login)
        self.botao_login.place(x=115, y=360)

        self.botao_cadastro= ctk.CTkButton(self.frame_login, text="Cadastro", width=200, height=40, corner_radius=20, fg_color="#03fc66", hover_color="#3afc88", command=self.tela_cadastro)
        self.botao_cadastro.place(x=115, y=430)

    def tela_cadastro(self):
        #remoção tela de login
        self.frame_login.place_forget()
        #criação tela cadastro
        self.frame_cadastro = ctk.CTkFrame(self, width=426 , height=580)
        self.frame_cadastro.place(x=426, y=70)
        self.cadastro_titulo = ctk.CTkLabel(master=self.frame_cadastro, text="CADASTRO",  font=("arial",30))
        self.cadastro_titulo.place(x=130, y=30)
        
        self.cadastro_nome_entry= ctk.CTkEntry(self.frame_cadastro, width=300, height=40, placeholder_text="Seu nome", border_color="#871fff", corner_radius=15)
        self.cadastro_nome_entry.place(x=60, y=120)

        self.cadastro_senha_entry= ctk.CTkEntry(self.frame_cadastro, width=300, height=40, placeholder_text="Sua senha", show="*", corner_radius=15, border_color="#871fff")
        self.cadastro_senha_entry.place(x=60, y=200)
        
        self.cadastro_csenha_entry= ctk.CTkEntry(self.frame_cadastro, width=300, height=40, placeholder_text="Confirme sua senha", show="*", border_color="#871fff", corner_radius=15)
        self.cadastro_csenha_entry.place(x=60, y=280)

        self.botao_cadastrar= ctk.CTkButton(self.frame_cadastro, text="Cadastrar", width=200, height=40, corner_radius=20, fg_color="#871fff", hover_color="#9a42ff", command=self.cadastrar_usuario)
        self.botao_cadastrar.place(x=115, y=360)

        self.botao_voltar= ctk.CTkButton(self.frame_cadastro, text="Voltar", width=100, height=40, corner_radius=20, fg_color="#b80000", hover_color="#b53535", command=self.tela_login)
        self.botao_voltar.place(x=165, y=430)


    def fecha_login(self): 
        self.janela_login.destroy()
        
       

    def abre_menu(self):
        menu = my_menu.Menu()
        menu.mainloop()    

    

    def limpa_entry_cadastro(self):
        self.cadastro_nome_entry.delete(0, END)
        self.cadastro_senha_entry.delete(0, END)
        self.cadastro_csenha_entry.delete(0, END)

    def limpa_entry_login(self):
        self.nome_entry.delete(0, END)
        self.senha_entry.delete(0, END)
    
app = App()
app.mainloop()


Tentei métodos diferentes e reiterar as funções, mas não consegui, gostaria só de entender o que devo fazer para este erro não afetar meu código futuramente

Tente usar quit() depois de destroy() na função fecha_login().
Esse erro acontece porque a função destroy() apenas destrói a janela mas o programa continua rodando. Se isso acontecer e o programa precisar usar a janela de novo esse erro vai aparecer.
Quando você coloca o quit() depois do destroy() você fecha o programa de fato e a mensagem de erro para de aparecer.
Apesar de que esse erro não tenha muitas chances de afetar seu programa futuramente mas ainda assim é uma boa ideia não deixar esse tipo de coisa acontecer.
Acredito que essa é a função com a alteração:
def fecha_login(self): 
    self.janela_login.destroy()
    self.janela_login.quit()

Essa resposta é baseada nessa pergunta
